# Populating multiple columns using code

Tags: vbscript

I am populating table using vb-script code :-

```
Set table = document.createElement("table")
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
i = 0
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)   
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
    Set td = document.createElement("td")
    td.innerText = node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & node.text
    tr.appendChild td
    tbody.appendChild tr
    i = i +1
Next
table.appendChild tbody
document.body.appendChild table
```

However I want to generate multiple columns my current output is :-

```
universespace->Milkyway 
universespace->Earth Layer 
scienceSubject->Solar System 
scienceItem->Earth 
scienceItem->Moon 
scienceItem->Mars
```

And I want it to be like :-

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|universespace1|universespace2|scienceSubject|scienceItem| 
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| Milkyway     | Earth Layer  | Solar System | Earth     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| Milkyway     | Earth Layer  | Solar System | Moon      |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| Milkyway     | Earth Layer  | Solar System | Mars      |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I tried various other ways :-

```
Set table = document.createElement("table")
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
i = 0
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)   
    Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
     Select Case True
     Case "namespace" = node.parentNode.nodeName 
        Set th = document.createElement("th")
        th.innerText =   node.parentNode.nodeName
        tr.appendChild th
      Case "namespace" = node.parentNode.nodeName
        Set th1 = document.createElement("th")
        th1.innerText =   node.parentNode.nodeName
        tr.appendChild th1
      Case "querySubject" = node.parentNode.nodeName
        Set th2 = document.createElement("th")
        th2.innerText =   node.parentNode.nodeName
        tr.appendChild th2
      Case "queryItem" = node.parentNode.nodeName
        Set th3 = document.createElement("th")
        th3.innerText =   node.parentNode.nodeName
        tr.appendChild th3
     End Select
    'td.innerText = i & node.parentNode.nodeName & "->" & i & node.text
    'tr.appendChild td
    tbody.appendChild tr
```

Still not able to get output in desired format. It is all coming in single column rather than different columns.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081205/generating-table) doesn't help me to create table with columns. It just displays a table with one row and one column i.e. table cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081205/generating-table)

Comment: Also duplicate of [Read text file and show in table vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36060599/692942)

Comment: Then give up on VBScript and went to Java and now back to VBScript. See [search text in xml file using java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36115367/692942).

Comment: No access to install anything in my environment like java, eclipse etc. so vbscript is the only choice I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could create the table. Learning to code so always asking stupid questions. :-)

```
Set table = document.createElement("table")
Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
i = 0
Set tr = document.createElement("tr")
set th = document.createElement("th")
th.innerHtml = "&nbsp;Namespace1 &nbsp;"
tr.appendChild th
set th = document.createElement("th")
th.innerHtml = "&nbsp; Namespace2 &nbsp;"
tr.appendChild th
set th = document.createElement("th")
th.innerHtml = "&nbsp; Query Subject &nbsp;"
tr.appendChild th
set th = document.createElement("th")
th.innerHtml = "&nbsp; Query Item &nbsp;"
tr.appendChild th
Set tr1 = document.createElement("tr")
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)   
    Set td = document.createElement("td")
    td.innerText = i & node.text
    tr1.appendChild td
    tbody.appendChild tr
    tbody.appendChild tr1
    i = i +1
Next
document.body.appendChild list
table.appendChild tbody
document.body.appendChild table
```